# apache mod_rewrite showing strange chars after url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite to remove .php from my urls but for some reason, mod_rewrite is adding strange chars after the url.

E.g. I go to:

http://www.mydomain.com.br/como-funciona

and I get redirected to:

http://www.mydomain.com.br/como-funciona#.UMkkyuR2x8E

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post your actual domain? Those hashes aren't from mod_rewrite; they're almost certainly from JavaScript on your page, probably from a tool that's helping you track when users share your site by copying and pasting the URL from the address bar.

Comment: Omg mjk, you are my new hero. it was the addthis code I had on my web. Thanks much. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

As @MJK pointed out, it was some code from addthis that was generating these strange urls. Thanks.